# How to make a discord bot that changes members nicknames based on what they type? Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So, I've been stuck for like a week trying to make a simple bot that does the following: When a person joins my server, they automatically get a role that let them see only one channel. On that channel, my bot'll send a message asking them what is their name on the game I play. The person'll answer and the bot'll store that info. Then, the bot'll ask for the game ID of this same person, then the bot'll change the nickname of the person to "NickName | ID" automatically, and after that give that person the role that let him see the server.

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(1044016033461182545)
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=1044016102998540398)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send(f"Bem Vindo ao {member.guild.name}, {member.mention}! Digite seu nome do Fusion: ")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    nickname = message.content
    channel = client.get_channel(1044016033461182545)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    print(nickname)


client.run('BOTTOKEN')
```

So as the member join, he gets the role from the role variable, and then he'll be asked to put his name on the chat, and the bot'll store that info on nickname variable. The print usage is for me to see if the variable nickname is getting what the user types, and its working fine. My trouble is to make the bot ask then the ID from the person and store that on another variable. How can I make that? I'm pretty new to python so im not used to it.

Comment: discord.py isn't really beginner friendly, you should probably get a bit more familiar with Python before attempting to make a bot.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to ask the person for their id. You can use the `member` parameter to automatically get the user's ID. You can look at the docs and see that the [member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) class has an attribute of id. So to find the ID of the user that joined the server use `member.id`. You could implement this into your code by assigning `member.id` to a variable like

```
var = member.id
```

I hope this helped

Comment: hey there, thanks for your comment! I was trying to find a way to make a member type his own nick, this nick would be his from the game that I play, I managed to do that using the command class, so when the member types "!nick (his nick) (his ID on the game)" his nickname turn into something like "MyNick / MyID". I would like to do that without needing to use a command tho.

Comment: Could you explain why you wouldn't like to use a command?

Comment: I would like the code to be more intuitive. I'm running it right now based on commands, and there's a lot of people who struggle to pass the registration section. They just type their game nicks and ID on the chat hoping that will work. So if I did that without needing to put a command before, it would save me a lot of time and trouble to manually add roles and change nicknames everytime.